# angular 8 with ngx-codemirror

Tags: angular, codemirror, angular8

I am new in angular. I want to codemirror in my Angular application. I created an Angular application using angular cli. On GitHub I found a Codemirror componente: ngx-codemirror. I followed the instructions as far as described. I have in my root project directory

npm install @ctrl/ngx-codemirror@2.0.0 codemirror

executed. My code currently looks like this: 
app/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CodemirrorModule } from '@ctrl/ngx-codemirror';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, FormsModule, CodemirrorModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app/app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const defaults = {
  markdown:
    '# Heading\n\nSome **bold** and _italic_ text\nBy [Scott Cooper](https://github.com/scttcper)',
  'text/typescript':
    `const component = {
  name: "@ctrl/ngx-codemirror",
  author: "Scott Cooper",
  repo: "https://github.com/typectrl/ngx-codemirror"
};
const hello: string = 'world';`,
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'MyBuilder';

  readOnly = false;
  mode = 'markdown';
  options: any = {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: this.mode,
  };
  defaults = defaults;

  changeMode() {
    this.options = {
      ...this.options,
      mode: this.mode,
    };
  }

  handleChange($event) {
    console.log('ngModelChange', $event);
  }

  clear() {
    this.defaults[this.mode] = '';
  }
}
```

app/app.component.html

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/cli">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
  <ngx-codemirror
    [options]="options"
    [ngModel]="defaults[mode]"
    [disabled]="readOnly"
    [autoFocus]="true"
    (ngModelChange)="handleChange($event)"
  ></ngx-codemirror>
</ul>
```

app/app.component.css

```
@import "~codemirror/lib/codemirror";
@import "~codemirror/theme/material";
```

But I don't see the  component. Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 3):

You should import the editor mode in the src/main.ts file:

```js
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app';

import 'codemirror/mode/markdown/markdown';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

And try importing the styles in the angular.json:

```js
 "styles": [
        "./node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css",
        "./node_modules/codemirror/theme/material.css"
]
```